# How to properly set TextField's background color and text color in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uiswitch

*Please don't mark as duplicate because I seem to have a bug where the usual code doesn't work. I went through all the available threads but haven't found a solution.*

I have the following cell:

[image]

When the `UISwitch` is turned off, I want the `UITextField` to be dark and text color bright. When turned on the opposite to simulate a "disable" behavior.

My code:

```
func setTextFieldActivation(isOn: Bool) {

    self.theTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = isOn

    self.theTextField.set(

        bgColor: isOn ? Colors.moreLightGrey : Colors.leastLightGray, //Colors is a global struct of UIColor to cache reused colors
        placeholderTxt: String(),
        placeholderColor: isOn ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
        txtColor: isOn ? Colors.black : Colors.white
    )
}
```

The extension `set`

```
extension UITextField {


    func set(bgColor: UIColor, placeholderTxt: String, placeholderColor: UIColor, txtColor: UIColor) {

        self.backgroundColor = bgColor
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderTxt, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor])
        self.textColor = txtColor
    }
}
```

The issue: When I turn on the `UISwitch`, the background color changes as wanted but the text color remains.

[image]

The weird part: When I click the `UITextField` and it becomes first responder, the text color changes to what I want.

[image]

But when I turn the Switch off again, the color remains dark.

[image]

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

PS: Xcode 9, Swift 3.

The code is called whenever the switch is changed:

```
self.theSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: .valueChanged)

func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {

    self.setTextFieldActivation(isOn: mySwitch.isOn)
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the text color anywhere else? I built a single text field test app with your code and it works. I had to add an initial call set(bgColor:, placeholderTxt:, placeholderColor:, txtColor:) in viewDidLoad().

Comment: No I do not change it anywhere else. The code is called whenever the switch is changed. See edit.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with when/where code is called? I use IBAction for UISwitch and call setTextFieldActivation(isOn: sender.isOn).

Comment: Do you call the `setTextFieldActivation` method on `viewDidLoad`? Maybe the initial values are not set and this messes up the behavior of switch actions.

Comment: It's inside a cell and I call it once the cell gets called in `cellForRow`

Comment: For test I have called the code in `awakeFromNib`, no change at all

Comment: Could it relate to the placeholder text? I see code to set its attributes, but no code passing it a value other than the empty String().

Comment: `self.theTextField.text = textFieldValue` is set in the cell init function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The wired thing is that the `textColor` is not updated until `layoutSubviews()`. I tried two approaches which seem to solve the problem.

The first approach is to call `layoutSubviews()` directly at the end of the `set` method

```
func set(bgColor: UIColor, placeholderTxt: String, placeholderColor: UIColor, txtColor: UIColor) {

    backgroundColor = bgColor
    attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderTxt, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor])
    textColor = txtColor

    layoutSubviews()
}
```

The second approach is to set the text for the `UITextField` to it's current value which will trigger `layoutSubviews()` as well.

```
func set(bgColor: UIColor, placeholderTxt: String, placeholderColor: UIColor, txtColor: UIColor) {

    backgroundColor = bgColor
    attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderTxt, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor])
    textColor = txtColor

    let newText = text
    text = newText
}
```

Comment: `layoutSubviews()` did it. thank you for your effort

Comment: What if I'm doing it inside a collectionView